# Different styles in footnote and bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I really like the style "philosophy-modern" for the bibliography at the end of the document. I also like to have verbose citations as footnotes.

```
bibstyle=philosophy-modern,
citestyle=philosophy-verbose,
```

enables me to have both. However "philosophy-modern" uses a lot of space in the footnote. Can I change to a different style in the footnote, but still have "philosophy-modern" in bibliography?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
    bibstyle=philosophy-modern,
    citestyle=philosophy-verbose,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample}

\title{Bibliography management: \texttt{biblatex} package}
\author{Share\LaTeX}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This document is an example of \texttt{biblatex} package using in bibliography
management. Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book
\autocite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \autocite{einstein}, and 
the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related items 
are \autocite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Without testing (there is nothing to test): Yes you can. Have you tried it out?

Comment: How can I specify a bibstyle for footnote?

Comment: You are using `citestyle=philosophy=verbose`, this is already another than p-modern.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. `citestyle=philosophy-verbose` is fine, but together with `bibstyle=philosophy-modern` I get footnotes in p-modern style and I want a different style for the footnotes

Comment: After you did provide a minimal example, i could see the issue. The documentation says, that the verbose style is meant for full bibliographical information in the footnotes, hence no own bibliography is printed. Using the `p-modern.bbx` hacks the cites, which was quite unexpected. i need to have a deeper look at the code, but i can't promise anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redefining the `postsep` as well as the bibmacro for the date, but all just for the citekeys, will do the trick.

[image: manuelschmidtBiblatexVerbose]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=philosophy-verbose,
    bibstyle=philosophy-modern,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \renewcommand{\postsep}{\space}%
    \renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
        \begingroup%
        \clearfield{month}%
        \clearfield{day}%
        \printtext{%
            \ifboolexpr{%
                test {\iffieldundef{date}}
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{year}}
            }%
            {\iftoggle{bbx:nodate}{\printtext{%
                \midsentence\bibstring{nodate}}}{}}%
                {\printtext{\printdateextra}}%
            }
    \endgroup}%
}

\setlength{\textheight}{11cm}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


This document is an example of \texttt{biblatex} package using in
bibliography management. Three items are cited: The
\LaTeX\ Companion book \autocite{companion}, the Einstein
journal paper \autocite{aristotle:physics}, and the Donald
Knuth's website \autocite{westfahl:space}. The \LaTeX\ related items 

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```